# How to increase Jupiter’s reflectivity?

Tags: moons, terraforming, habitability, gas-giants, sunlight

The idea of turning Jupiter into a sun to terraform the Galilean moons is a popular one. This concept goes by the alluring name of “stellification,” but has a few important drawbacks when prodded with the pointy stick of actual proper science.

One is that, if Jupiter became a star, any moons orbiting it would not simply be warmed to habitability. They would be cooked. But it occurs to me, there is another option:

The planet 47 Ursae Majoris b is a gas giant approximately 46 lightyears away. It orbits its star at a distance of 2.1 AU; too far to lie within the habitable zone, but close enough for its atmosphere to be filled with clouds of water vapour that give it a very high albedo indeed.

It is speculated that the high reflectivity of this 47UMb means that any suitably-sized moons orbiting the planet could receive enough reflected sunlight to sustain liquid water on their surfaces. Thus, the gas giant does function as a “sun” of sorts, but not to the extent of cooking the worlds orbiting it.

Now, obviously jupiter cannot simply be given water vapour clouds. But the idea, I believe, is sound. So, **is there a way that Jupiter’s reflectivity could be raised sufficiently for the moons orbiting it to be habitable?** preferably over geological timespans, on the order of a million years or more.

Comment: The [albedo of Jupiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albedo#Optical_or_visual_albedo) is 0.54 geometric, 0.51 Bond. It cannot be greater than 1. The champion among the planets is Venus with an albedo of 0.69 geometric, 0.76 Bond. The point being that there is only limited room for improvement; even if you made Jupiter as reflective as Venus, the amount of solar energy received by one of its satellites would increase by only about 17%.

Answer (score 4):

Copy Venus.

It shines so bright because its SO2 and H2SO4 rich clouds do a great job at reflecting back solar light.

Hydrogen is readily available on Jupiter, sulphur and oxygen though in traces should be sufficient to produce enough of what you need.

The main problem will be having enough energy to turn the elements into the desired compound. You might use jovian lightning for that.

Comment: Do you mean jovian lightning? I would edit but I don't know if giovian is also a thing.

Comment: How long is the H2SO4 likely to stay in the atmosphere? Aren’t there any natural processes on Jupiter that will remove it over time?

Comment: @user98816 spot-on. Sulfuric acid at Jupiter will reduce to H2S and H2O (and Jupiter has a lot of both in its cloud systems)

Answer (score 1):

A frame challenge.

According to AlexP's comment, it would be impossible to increase the light reflected from Jupiter enough to heat up the moons enough for life.

I also note that the only Jovian moons which seem likely candidates for having life are the four Galilean moons - Io, Europa, Ganymede, and Callisto. The other moons are far too small to retain atmospheres sufficient to retain liquid water on the surface.

The semi-major axes of the orbits of the Galilean moons are:

Io: 421,800 kilometers.

Europa: 671,100 kilometers, 1.591 times that of Io.

Ganymede: 1,070,400 kilometers, 2.537 times that of Io and 1.594 times that of Europa.

Callisto: 1,882,700 Kilometers, 4.463 times that of Io, 2.805 times that of Europa, and 1.759 times that of Ganymede.

There is a list of estimates of the inner and outer edges, or both edges, of the Sun's circumstellar habitable zone.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumstellar_habitable_zone#Solar_System_estimates

Some of those estimates of the relative width of the the Sun's circumstellar habitable zone are wide enough that two or more of the moon's of Jupiter might be habitable if all their light came from Jupiter.  Other estimates of the Sun's habitable zone are very narrow, so that it is surprising that one planet, Earth, orbits within that narrow zone.  According to those estimates no more than one moon of Jupiter could possibly orbit within the Jovian habitable zone.

Of course Jupiter isn't the only source of light for the Galilean moons.  Most of their light comes from the Sun, and they also get some light reflected from  Jupiter.

Thus maybe it might be possible for not one or two, but two or three, of the Jovian moons to have liquid water temperatures due to light from the Sun augmented by reflected light from Jupiter.

Except that the Earth orbits the Sun at 1 AU and Jupiter orbits the Sun at 5.2038 AU, 5.2038 times as far.  Thus Jupiter and its moons receive 1 divided by (5.2038 times 5.2038), or 1/27.079534, or 0.0369282, times as much light and heat from the Sun as Earth receives.

And it seems obvious to me that no moon of Jupiter could possible receive more sunlight reflected from Jupiter than it receives directly from the Sun, and most would receive much, much less reflected light even if Jupiter was a perfect reflector.  So no moon of Jupiter could possibly receive more sunlight than 0.0738564 the amount Earth receives from the Sun, even if Jupiter was a perfect reflector.

So even with reflected sunlight from Jupiter, none of the Moons could be warm enough for liquid water using life.

Thus it may seem extremely improbable that there will ever be a Jovian goon from a Jovian moon.

But I will have much more to write on the topic later.

Another problem with terraforming the Galilean moons is their ability, or lack of it, to retain an atmosphere for geological eras of time.

Apparently there are complicated formulas to calculate how long a particular world will retain its atmosphere.

According to Stephen Dole in *Habitable Planets for Man*, 1964, pages 34-35, a rule of thumb for estimating how long a world can retain its atmosphere uses the ratio of the world's escape velocity divided by the root-men-square of a gas's velocity in the exosphere of thee world's atmosphere.  The velocity of a gas depends on its temperature.

Table 5 on page 35 gives some examples of how long the amount of gas in an atmosphere will take to go down to 0.368 of its original amount with different ratios.

If the ratio is one or two, the gas will go down to 0.368almost instantly.  If the ratio is three, it will take weeks.  If the ratio if four it will take a few thousand years.  If the ration is five, it will take about a hundred million years. If the ratio is six, it will take about infinity.

If it takes a time of 1X for the amount of a gas to drop to 0.368, it will take 2X for the gas to drop to 0.135, 3X for the gas to drop to 0.049, 4 X for the gas to drop to 0.018, 5X for the gas to drop to 0.0067, and so on.

According to Dole, the minimum survivable oxygen pressure is 60 mmHg, and the maximum survivable pressure of oxygen is about 400 mmHG.   The minimum pressure of oxygen is about 0.15 of the maximum survivable pressure of oxygen.

So even if a world starts out with the maximum survivable oxygen pressure of 400 mmHg, the oxygen will drop to less than minimum survivable pressure in less than two times the time for oxygen to drop to 0.368 of the original amount.

In order for oxygen to be replenished fast enough to compensate for loss into space, the ratio of the world's escape velocity divided by the root-mean-square velocity of oxygen in the world's exosphere should be rather high, preferably at least between five and six.

Io has an escape velocity of 2.558 kilometers per second, Europa 2.025 kilometers per second, Ganymede 2.741 kilometers per second, and Callisto 2.441 kilometers per second.  By comparison, Titan, the largest moon of Saturn, has an escape velocity of 2.641 kilometers per second.

So if you desire to terraform the Galilean moons to be habitable for humans and other multi celled life forms you will have to give them dense, oxygen rich atmospheres, and for the oxygen to last long enough to be worthwhile, the route-mean-square velocity of oxygen in the exosphere must be no more than 0.3375 to 0.405 kilometers per second for Europa and no more than 0.456 to 0.548 kilometers per second for Ganymede.

And Titan, the largest moon of Saturn, has an escape velocity between those of Callisto and Ganymede.  And titan has a dense, mostly nitrogen, atmosphere even denser than that of Earth, one that is billions of times as dense as the utterly thin atmospheres of Ganymede and Callisto.

And there is considerable uncertainty about the reasons for such a vast difference in atmospheres.

It is believed that gases in the exospheres of worlds are heated to high temperatures - and thus high root-men-square velocities - by ultraviolet light from the Sun.  Saturn and Titan orbit about twice was far from the Sun as Jupiter and its moons, and so receive only about a quarter as much ultraviolet from the Sun as the Jovian Moons.  And maybe - repeat maybe -that is one contributing reason why the atmosphere of Titan is so much dense that those of Ganymede and Callisto.

If that turns out to be the case, any terraforming project to give the Galilean moons oxygen rich atmospheres would probably have to shield their exosphere  from ultrviolet light, perhaps by building giant cylindrical sunshades orbiting each of those moons.

Those hypothetical sunshades would have to be transparent to most frequencies of visible light and infra red but opaque to ultraviolet light.  Opaque enough to reduce the ultraviolet to 25 percent or less of that arriving from the Sun.  Of course if a world orbited a star much cooler than the Sun, the amount of ultraviolet might be reduced enough even without those sun shades.

Or you could build a roof over each moon that you terraform to hold in the oxygen rich atmosphere.  That would be a somewhat smaller project than building the giant sunshades.

Ro be continued.